# Docker container with Python Web App - Connect to Postgres on Host machine (OSX)

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

I can connect to my local Postgres DB in my web app, but **NOT** if I am running the web app inside of a Docker container.

- Web app running inside of a Docker container
- Postgres running in the Host machine

I am not sure if it is related to the Postgres connection settings or to the Docker network settings.

Follow my settings and commands:

**Host**:

- OSX 10.11.6
- PostgreSQL 9.6

**Docker container**

- Docker 1.13.1
- Docker-machine 0.9.0
- Docker container OS: python:3.6.0-alpine
- Python 3.6 + psycopg2==2.7

**postgresql.conf**:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

**pg_hba.conf**

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
host    all             all             172.17.0.0/24           trust
host    all             all             192.168.99.0/24       trust
```

## With Docker network in HOST mode

```
docker run -i --net=host -h 127.0.0.1 -e POSTGRES_URI=postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/db my/image
```

Error:

> could not connect to server: Connection refused
>     Is the server running
>   on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

## With Docker network in BRIDGE mode

```
docker run -i --add-host=dockerhost:`docker-machine ip ${DOCKER_MACHINE}` -e POSTGRES_URI=postgresql://dockerhost:5432/db -p 8000:8000 -p 5432:5432 my/image
```

Error:

> server closed the connection unexpectedly
>   This probably means the
>   server terminated abnormally  before or while processing the request.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any particular reason for not running postgres in a container as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a note about doing this in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host)

> **I want to connect from a container to a service on the host**
>
> The Mac has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). Our current recommendation is to attach an unused IP to the `lo0` interface on the Mac; for example: `sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 10.200.10.1/24`, and make sure that your service is listening on this address or `0.0.0.0` (ie not `127.0.0.1`). Then containers can connect to this address.

Comment: I was able to connect to the external service with this tip, thanks! I missed that.

Comment: @PauloCheque, glad I could help. Don't forget to mark answers that solve your problem as correct. That helps other people who come across your question.